# Proof check: Suprema

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to prove the answer to a question on [one of Terence Tao's Java-based math quizzes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/java/MultipleChoice/infsup.txt), relating to suprema and infima. Below is the question, along with the answer:

> **Question:**  Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets [of real numbers].  Which of the following statements would be equivalent to saying that $\sup(A) \le \sup(B)$?
>
> **Correct Answer:** For every $a$ in $A$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $b$ in $B$ such that $a < b + \epsilon$.

### Attempt at a proof:

I'll begin with two lemmas, the first of which is also the subject of another question on the same quiz:

> **Lemma 1:** Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $L$ be a real number.  If $\sup(A) < L$, then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that every element of $A$ is less than $L - \epsilon$.

My (attempted) proof of this lemma (**is this proof valid?**):

Let $\delta=L-\sup(A)$. This quantity is positive by the hypothesis of the lemma. By the definition of supremum, we have $\forall a \in A$, $a \le \sup(A)=L-\delta$.

Now, this is close to what we are trying to show, but the lemma states that every element of $A$ is **strictly** less than $L-\epsilon$.

To remedy this, let $\epsilon = \frac{\delta}2$. Clearly (**is it?**), $0 < \frac{\delta}2 < \delta$, so $L-\delta < L-\epsilon $.

Thus, $\forall a \in A$, $a \le \sup(A)=L-\delta < L-\epsilon$, and therefore

$$
\forall a \in A, a < L-\epsilon.
$$

Since such an $\epsilon$ can always be found (just let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}(L-\sup A)$), the proof is complete.

---

The second lemma states that the converse of Lemma 1 also holds:

> **Lemma 2:** Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $L$ be a real number.  If there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that every element of $A$ is less than $L - \epsilon$, then $\sup(A)<L$.

**Attempted proof:**

Since $L-\epsilon$ is greater than every element of $A$, $L-\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $A$, and therefore
$L-\epsilon \ge \sup(A).$

Since $\epsilon>0$, we have that $L > L-\epsilon \ge \sup(A)$, which implies that

$$\sup(A) < L,$$

as desired.

---

**Now, continuing with our main proof:**

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets of real numbers.

Let $P$ denote the statement that $\sup(A)\le\sup(B)$.

Let $Q$ denote the statement that $(\forall a \in A)(\forall\epsilon > 0) (\exists b \in B)[a<b+\epsilon]$.

Instead of proving $P \iff Q$, I will instead try to show that $\neg P \iff \neg Q$. **(Is this a valid way to show the original equivalence?)**

Note the following symbolic representations for $\neg P$ and $\neg Q$:
$$\neg P: \sup(B) < \sup(A) $$

$$\neg Q: (\exists a \in A)(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)[a \ge b+\epsilon] $$

Finally, note that I will use U.B. to stand for upper bound.

**First attempt:**

\begin{align}
\neg P &\iff \sup(B)<\sup(A)\\[1ex]
   &\iff (\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)[b < \sup(A) - \epsilon] && \text{(By Lemmas 1 and 2)} \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)[b + \epsilon < \sup(A)] \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)[\text{$b+\epsilon$ is not a U.B. for $A$}] && \text{(*)} \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)(\exists a \in A)[a>b+\epsilon]
\end{align}

This is as far as I could get on this attempt.

The last equivalent statement is not equivalent to $\neg Q$, because of the difference in the order of quantifiers and the presence of a strong inequality as opposed to a weak inequality.

Additionally, I'm not sure that the fourth equivalence (marked with a (*)) is valid. I know that if $x < \sup(A) $, then $x$ is not an upper bound for $A$. **I believe the converse also holds:** If $x$ is not an upper bound for $A$, then there exists an $a \in A$ such that $x < a$, and since $a \le \sup(A)$, $x < \sup(A)$.

**Second attempt:**

\begin{align}
   \neg P &\iff \sup(B)<\sup(A)\\[1ex]
&\iff \text{$\sup(B)$ is not a U.B. for $A$} && \text{(*)} \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists a \in A)[\sup(B)<a] \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists a \in A)(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)[b < a-\epsilon] &&\text{(By Lemmas 1 and 2)} \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists a \in A)(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)[a > b+\epsilon]\\[1ex]
\end{align}

Again, I'm not fully sure that the second equivalence (marked with a (*)) is valid, for the same reason why I questioned the fourth equivalence in the first attempt above.

Putting that aside, we see that in this attempt, the last equivalent statement is closer to $\neg Q$, but they are still not equivalent, as the former still has a strong inequality instead of a weak one. However, this last statement *does* **imply** $\neg Q$, because if $a > b+\epsilon$, then certainly $a \ge b + \epsilon$. In other words, the steps above appear to show that $\neg P \implies \neg Q$. But it's not clear to me how one could *begin* at $\neg Q$ and *arrive* at $\neg P$, which is needed to establish the implication in the other direction.

The only idea that comes to mind is to do something similar to what I did in the proof of Lemma 1. In other words, start with the $\epsilon$ which, according to $\neg Q$, exists and satisfies the **weak inequality**, and then divide the value of $\epsilon$ by e.g. $2$ to obtain a *new* $\epsilon_0$ which satisfies the **strict inequality**. More concretely, if
$a \ge b + \epsilon$ and $0 < \frac{1}{2}\epsilon =\epsilon_0 < \epsilon$, then

$$a \ge b+\epsilon > b + \epsilon_0,$$

so

$$a > b + \epsilon_0.$$

Does this modification "bridge the gap" and show that $\neg Q \implies \neg P$? I think so:
\begin{align}
\neg Q &\iff (\exists a \in A)(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)[a \ge b+\epsilon] \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists a \in A)(\exists \epsilon_0 > 0)(\forall b \in B)[a > b+\epsilon_0] && \text{Let $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon$} \\[1ex]
\end{align}

The key change is that now we can go from the strict inequality to the weak one **in both directions**. Going from strict to weak, no changes are needed. Going from the weak one to the strict one, just let $\epsilon_0=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$.

**Revised attempt at the proof:**

\begin{align}
   \neg P &\iff \sup(B)<\sup(A)\\[1ex]
&\iff \text{$\sup(B)$ is not a U.B. for $A$} \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists a \in A)[\sup(B)<a] \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists a \in A)(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)[b < a-\epsilon] && \text{(By Lemmas 1 and 2)} \\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists a \in A)(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall b \in B)[a > b+\epsilon]\\[1ex]
&\iff (\exists a \in A)(\exists \epsilon_1 > 0)(\forall b \in B)[a \ge b+\epsilon_1] && \text{Let $\epsilon_1 = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon$}\\[1ex]
&\iff \neg Q
\end{align}

Since $\neg P \iff \neg Q$, $P \iff Q$.

---

Does this final attempt constitute a valid proof? Is there an easier way of establishing the equivalence?